# Aptana changed my Eclipse color scheme, and I want it back

Tags: colors, eclipse

I installed Aptana Studio 3 as an Eclipse plugin. Generally, it works OK, but Aptana thought that a dark background is cool and elegant (apparently). But I liked my old color scheme with a white background, especially because we have these stupid glare type monitors at the office, which do not lend themselves well to a dark background (except for people that like staring at their mirror image all day...).

Are there any good light color schemes for Aptana/Eclipse around that I could use?

Comment: That dark Aptana theme is completely illegible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it: it's in Preferences > Aptana > Themes. I looked in Preferences > General > Appearance all the time and didn't think about looking in Aptana's own settings.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can normally compare files (SVN) cause with its default theme Aptana was making the differences invisible.